# Should I capitalise a lower-case last name at the start of a sentence?

Tags: style, formatting

I have a fairly quick question. I am wondering if I should capitalize a last name when it comes at the start of a sentence if it starts with a lower-case letter.

Example: In my essay, I am citing Alexis de Tocqueville. After I've introduced him I have a sentence that is something along the lines of "de Tocqueville stated XYZ", with the "de" being the first word in the sentence. **Should I capitalize "de", or leave it as is because that's how it's formatted in his name?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** See https://www.dictionary.com/e/when-to-capitalize-words/

> The First Word of a Sentence
>
> You should always capitalize the first letter of the first word in a sentence, no matter what the word is.

This is the first rule listed, probably because it's the easiest one. Of course, like all rules, it *can* be broken for stylistic effect if you know what you're doing.